# Passing a value of a textbox from View to a method/action in Controller and then data from response back to form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form in a create view (not sure if relevant but is done with ChameleonForms).

Bellow of an edit box named let say "CompanyNumber" I have an html button and I want that OnClick to send the value already written of edit box as parameter to an method in my Controller but without submitting the form, because before saving the form I have to manually add fields value that are not retrieved with json response.

Mainly the method make a webrequest and returns a json that I use in method to populate the model relevant to the given view with all available information that I can get.

So at this moment I have this in the view:

```
@*Form region*@
@s.FieldFor(m => m.CompanyNumber)
<button id="Ask" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Ask the web!</button>
@*Script region*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Ask').click(function(){

        var companynumber = $('#CompanyNumber').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:{CompanyNumber:companynumber},
            //url from the controller's action method
            url: '@Url.Action("Customers","GetCompanyInfo")/?CompanyNumber='+$('#CompanyNumber').val(),
            //with the following 2 lines, raise HTTP500
            //dataType: 'json',
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (data) {
                //Here you would update the textboxes, the 'data' variable contains the html from the partialview
                //alert("here we have: " + data.d.toString());
            },
            error: function () {
                //Manage errors
            }
        });

    }
)
</script>
```

and in Controller:

```
    private InvoiceDBEntities db = new InvoiceDBEntities();
    public Customers cModel = new Customers();
    //Ask the web for company details
    public ActionResult GetCompanyInfo(string CompanyNumber)
    {
        //call for openapi.ro
        string CompanyCUI = CompanyNumber;
        // Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
        Uri myUri = new Uri("https://api.openapi.ro/api/companies/" + CompanyCUI + ".json");
        // Create a new request to the above mentioned URL. 
        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        //Add the required header to request
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "some_key_relevant_to_me_and_my_scenario");
        // Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        // Read the response into a stream
        var dataStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        var jsonResultString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Deserialize
        var CompanyInfoData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerModels>(jsonResultString);
        //Bind to model for feed him

        cModel.Phone1 = CompanyInfoData.telefon;
        cModel.CompanyRegistration = CompanyInfoData.numar_reg_com;
        cModel.Name = CompanyInfoData.denumire;
        cModel.CompanyNumber = CompanyInfoData.cif;
        cModel.Address = CompanyInfoData.adresa;
        //other properties of the related model....


        ViewData["Customer"] = cModel;

        return View(cModel);
    }

    //other actions

    // GET: Customers/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Customers/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,Name,CompanyNumber,CompanyRegistration,CompanyBank,CompanyIBAN,Address,CP,City,ContactPerson,Phone1,Phone2,Fax,Email,Notes")] Customers customers)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Customers.Add(customers);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customers);
    }
```

At the end I obtain the required json response and I fill my model with data. 
So my question is how to instruct the method to send back the obtained values to be rendered as text values to relevant editboxes in the same form?

After this I will be able to do validation checks and other stuff before sending the form to saving

I have to say that at first step I experimented this, with CompanyNumber hardcoded into my method, (in fact all method code was inside the default Index action of controller) and for Index view associated with the Controller it works fine, the form was filled with all available data values that I was able to retrieve.

Regards

Comment: Your making a GET, so you need to use javascript to build the url based on the value of the textbox (`ViewData["CompanyNumber"]` just posts back the original value, not theedited value) and you should remove the `Customers customer` parameter since you not posting back a `Customers` model.

Comment: I have tried this: '$('#Ask').click(function() {
  var companynumber = $('#CompanyNumber').val(); // get the textbox value
  var url = $(this).attr('href') + '?CompanyNumber=' + companynumber; // build new url
  location.href = url; // redirect
  return false; // cancel default redirect' but in controller action it comes no value (I've already removed Customers customer) (sorry I don't know why here I can't format the code)

Comment: Edit your question with the code you have tried (not in comments)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: What is `@s.FieldFor(m => m.CompanyNumber)`? If its `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyNumber)` and you change the `url:` option to `url: '@Url.Action("Customers","GetCompanyInfo")` (your already passing the data in the `data:` option) then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an ajax call pointing to the action in the controller, and retrive the information as a partial view (or json, depending on the circunstances). The following example uses JQuery

```
    $(#Ask).click(function(){
    var companynumber = $('#CompanyNumber').val();

   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
        CompanyNumber:companynumber
    },
    //url from the controller's action method
    url: url,

    success: function (data) {
        //Here you would update the textboxes, the 'data'
        //variable contains the html from the partialview
    },
    error: function () {  
       //Manage errors
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: I have tried the suggestion above, but simply don't work: the URL is finally wrong constructed (it gives http://localhost:58884/Customers/GetCompanyInfo/Ask instead of e.g. http://localhost:58884/Customers/GetCompanyInfo?CompanyNumber=22052442) and at Action comes no parameter. I modified in question, the code acodingly.

Comment: You are not passing the url parameter correctly, It should be url: "/ControllerName/Method"

Comment: it was a typo, but anyway it still does nothing.

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in the controller's method? Which value CompanyNumber gets?

Comment: In action this time the parameter that is come, is not null, but is empty string (no matter that is write it in editbox, even if I inspect the page in Chrome, it does not show nor in plain HTML the value that I write in it; don't know if is normal or not). Just before this when inspecting value for parameter it was null.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the source js, just before the ajax call, do you see the value of CompanyNumber ?

Comment: Finally I succeeded to have the parameter for my method. Now at the end of method I have the json response with all data I need from remote public  service and this info is bind to my relevant model.  I will check if relevant changes to update in code in question. I just need a way to send all this data back to my form, for being then able to go further. For testing purpose if I do all of this in Index action (with a return View(cModel); ) if in Index view I put a form that is bind to cModel model, when View is rendered, all fields of form are filled with required data

Answer (score 0):

Finally I make it working
I will add only relevant for who may need a similar stuff:

The script at the end of the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Ask').click(function () {

        var companynumber = $('#CompanyNumber').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                CompanyNumber: companynumber
            },
            //url from the controller's action method e.g. GetCompanyInfo
            url: '/Customers/GetCompanyInfo/',
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data) {
                //Here you would update the textboxes, the 'data' variable contains the html/text from the fill
                $('#CompanyNumber').val(data.cif);
                $('#CompanyRegistration').val(data.numar_reg_com);
                $('#Name').val(data.denumire);
                $('#Phone1').val(data.telefon);
                $('#Fax').val(data.fax);
                $('#Address').val(data.adresa);
                $('#ZIP').val(data.cod_postal);
                //alert("here: " + data.toString());
            },
            error: function () {
                //Manage errors
            }

        });
        //console.log();
    }
)
</script>
```

The controller (simplified):

```
 public ActionResult GetCompanyInfo(string CompanyNumber)
    {
        //call for openapi.ro
        string CompanyCUI = CompanyNumber;
        // Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
        Uri myUri = new Uri("https://api.openapi.ro/api/companies/" + CompanyCUI + ".json");
        // Create a new request to the above mentioned URL. 
        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        //Add the required header to request
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "some_key_relevant_to_me_and_my_scenario");
        // Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        // Read the response into a stream
        var dataStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        var jsonResultString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Deserialize
        var CompanyInfoData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerModels>(jsonResultString);

        return Json(CompanyInfoData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and the form part of the view (in my case done with ChameleonForms, but don't important):

```
@using ChameleonForms
@using ChameleonForms.Component
@using ChameleonForms.Enums
@using ChameleonForms.Templates
@using ChameleonForms.ModelBinders

@model DirectInvoice.Models.Customers

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<div>
@using (var f = Html.BeginChameleonForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    using (var s = f.BeginSection("Add a new customer"))
    {
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.CompanyNumber)
        @*<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetCompanyInfo", "Customers", new { id = "Ask" })'" class="btn btn-default">Ask the web!</button>*@
        <button id="Ask" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Ask the web!</button>
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.Name)
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.CompanyRegistration)
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.Phone1).Placeholder("0XX X XXX XXX")
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.Fax).Placeholder("0XX X XXX XXX")
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.Email).Placeholder("name@email.com")
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.Address)
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.ZIP)
        @s.FieldFor(m => m.City)


    }
    using (var n = f.BeginNavigation())
    {
        @n.Submit("Save the new customer...")
    }
}
</div>
```

Thank you to all for ideas!

Comment: Adding `/?CompanyNumber=' + $('#CompanyNumber').val(),` to the end of the url is pointless. Adding `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",`is pointless.